How to end a currently active Telegram bot conversation and start a new one using specific keywords in Python
I’m building a Telegram bot using python-telegram-bot, and I’m using a ConversationHandler to manage conversations. Here's my handler setup:
python

conv_handler = ConversationHandler( entry_points=[CommandHandler("start", start)], states={ 
CHOOSING: [MessageHandler(filters.TEXT & ~filters.COMMAND, choose)],
ECHO: [MessageHandler(filters.TEXT & ~filters.COMMAND, echo)], },
fallbacks=[CommandHandler("cancel", cancel)] )

The bot works as expected: users can navigate between the CHOOSING and ECHO states. However, I want to interrupt the current conversation and start a new one based on a new message sent to the user.
For example, if the user is in the middle of the CHOOSING state and I send a message like this through the bot:
python

keyboard = ReplyKeyboardMarkup([["Confirm", "Cancel"]], resize_keyboard=True, one_time_keyboard=True)
await send_message_to_user( context, post_creator_user_id, "Please take action to confirm or reject the request.", keyboard=keyboard )

I want the new conversation to handle responses based on the "Confirm" and "Cancel" buttons. Once the user selects one of these options, the previous conversation should end, and the new one should begin.
How can I:

Reset the current conversation state when sending this new message?

Start handling a new conversation flow with the "Confirm" and "Cancel" options?


